# How create custom rich snippet for specific part of page

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets

I am wondering how can it possible to display part of website as rich snippets in google search result?
For example in this website there is a section of page that show in search results as rich snippets.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try searching for rich results at https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways. I can not read the language of your example, but I'm guessing the first is the carousel:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/carousel

or the products, which is and has been under recent refinements:

https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2022/08/pros-and-cons-structured-data

And the second maybe the rich cards

https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2016/11/rich-cards-expands-to-more-verticals

Generally this is done using the schema so that the content can easily go beyond Google https://www.bing.com/webmasters/help/marking-up-your-site-with-structured-data-3a93e731

Although some are available via google seach console.

### Resources:

All Schemas https://schema.org/docs/schemas.html

Google Feature Guides, they don't have a direct link, but the menu on the left goes through each one as seen on google. Article is the first. https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/article

Answer (score -1):

insert JSON-LD structured data into head element of your web page. follow guidelines .

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/intro-structured-data

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. They want to know how to get that specific rich snippet. If it is powered by structured data, which structured data should they use?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).